# Unable to login to sonarqube from jenkins

Tags: authentication, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

We have a system where we have connected Jenkins and sonarqube.We are using crowd for authentication in Sonar Qube. We have both in the same server. Earlier analysis used to be successful. 
But now we are getting this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password
```

We have specified sonar.login and sonar.password of an internal user(default admin).
Anyone could you please help us.

Comment: You say "Earlier analysis used to be successful": what have you changed since that time?

Comment: First of all thanks for your response. The problem has got solved now. The credentials we used in configure Jenkins section, to connect sonarqube from Jenkins had got expired. Now we are using working credentials. It is fine now.

Comment: Happy to hear that! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has got solved now. The credentials we used in configure Jenkins section, to connect sonarqube from Jenkins had got expired. Now we are using working credentials. It is fine now.